# css3 transition is not smooth in iphone6

Tags: iphone, css

I didn't the get the same smooth effect for iphone6's safari which I got in other browsers.

This is what i tried:

```
-webkit-transition: right 700ms ease;
transition: right 700ms ease;
```

This happens only in iphone6's safari.

Comment: iphone6 u mean safari right?

Answer (score 0):

add "opacity" property to element. for example.

```
.my-div {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: right 700ms ease, opacity 700ms ease;
}
```

I haven't tried on iphone6 but it may help.

Comment: Still its not fine, i have used this for my site mobile navigation. usually mobile navigation div is in right: 0; if i click the button then it should be visible(right: 240px);  @Ararat Harutyunyan